# Big O notation of $O(n/(m-n))$

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I'm new to the complexity theory and have a basic question about the big-O notation that I encountered.

I came across a complexity of $O\big(\frac{n}{m-n}\big)$, where both $n$ and $m$ are independent variables in my algorithm (assuming $m \geq n$). Since I haven't encountered the subtraction of two variables in the denominator before, I'm curious if it can be simplified further, perhaps to $O\big(\frac{n}{m}\big)$ or other nicer forms. I've thought about it for some time, and maybe dividing the fraction by $n$ gives $O\big(\frac{1}{\frac{m}{n}-1}\big) = O\big(\frac{1}{\frac{m}{n}}\big) = O\big(\frac{n}{m}\big)$, but not sure if this is correct.

Additionally, I'm wondering about the whether  containing expressions like $m-n$ is common or not. Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a better conclusion in the general case:

- if $m$ is almost $n$ (not equal to $n$, otherwise $\frac{n}0$ is not defined), then it is $\mathcal{O}(n)$;
- if $m$ is big enough compared to $n$ (meaning $m\geqslant (1 + \varepsilon) n$, with $\varepsilon > 0$ being a constant), then it is $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

You cannot conclude that it is $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$ in the general case, because you neglected $1$ in front of $\frac{m}{n}$, but you cannot always do that, for example when $m = n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

n / (m-n) is undefined for m = n. It is equal to +/- n if m = n +/- 1. But for example for m = 0 or m = 2n it is just +/- 1.

You can’t really simplify this. For fixed n, you have a function that goes from 1 to n in a hyperbola, then from -n to -1 and getting still closer to 0, also in a hyperbola. Look out if n, m are dependent of each other or if the result is used in some interesting way.